# Python 3.x random input for lists

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import randint

List = [randint(0,99)*20]
print(List)
```

How could i go along the lines of make it into a list for 20 different random numbers between 0 and 99? The code i have ends up multiplying one random number 20 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint

List = [randint(0,99) for i in range(20)]
print("%3s" % List)
List.sort()
print("%3s" % List)
```

My primary is Java. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
List = [randint(0,99) for i in range(20)]
```